# Bootstrap-table PrintPageBuilder Explanation needed for adding title to the print sheet

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-table

I started using bootstrap-table recently. I'm using the print extension to print tables. I managed to print using the default print option but I want to add a title to the page being printed.

Can someone give a brief explanation on how to use the printPageBuilder option in bootstrap-table. I have found few information but none of them seems to work.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a nixe example https://live.bootstrap-table.com/code/wenzhixin/510